# Obtaining the stationary distribution for a Markov Chain using eigenvectors from large matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, eigenvector, markov-chains

I am trying to find the stationary distribution of a Markov chain. I have a transition probability matrix (TPM).
Here is the code:

```
[V, D] = eigs(double(TPM'),1); 
Py = abs(V)/sum(V);
```

My problem is that `sum(V) < 0` so it gives me some negative values in the vector `Py`. I've tested the code using another probability matrix and it gives `sum(V) > 0`.

I don't know what is the problem, is it the TPM or the code I am using?

**EDIT:**

Here is a more "elaborated" version of the code (including the answer of "SecretAgentMan", see method 3):

```
function [Py1, Py2, Py3] = testStatDist(TPM)

% method 1
[V1, D1] = eigs(double(TPM'),1);

% method 2
[V2, D2] = iterator(TPM);

% method 3
V3 = null(eye(size(TPM))-TPM.'); 

if(abs(D1 - 1) > 1e-5)
    warning(0, 'testStatDist.m: Check Transition Matrix');
    exit;
end

if(abs(D2 - 1) > 1e-5)
    warning(0, 'testStatDist.m: Check Transition Matrix');
    exit;
end

% res 1
Py1 = abs(V1)/sum(V1);

% res 2
Py2 = abs(V2)/sum(V2);

% res 3
Py3 = abs(V3)/sum(V3);
end
```

Here is the function "iterator":

```
function [V, D] = iterator(TPM)

pi(1:length(TPM)) = 1/length(TPM);
error = 1;
budget = 1000;
while(error >= 1e-10)
    pi2 = pi*TPM;
    error = sum((pi - pi2).^2);
    pi = pi2;
    budget = budget - 1;
    if(budget == 0)
        break;
    end
end
V = pi';
D = 1;
```

And here is one of the TPMs that I am using:

```
TPM = [0.987665198237886    0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.000881057268722467    0.985682819383260   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.983700440528634   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0.988986784140969   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.00440528634361233 0   0   0   0.983259911894273   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0.00440528634361233 0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.981277533039648   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0.00440528634361233 0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.979295154185022   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0.00440528634361233 0   0   0   0.984581497797357   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0.00881057268722467 0   0   0   0.978854625550661   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0.00881057268722467 0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.976872246696035   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00881057268722467 0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.974889867841410   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00881057268722467 0   0   0   0.980176211453745   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0132158590308370  0   0   0   0.974449339207049   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0132158590308370  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.972466960352423   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0132158590308370  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.970484581497797   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0132158590308370  0   0   0   0.975770925110132   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0176211453744493  0   0   0   0.970044052863436   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0176211453744493  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.968061674008811   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0176211453744493  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.966079295154185   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0176211453744493  0   0   0   0.971365638766520   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0220264317180617  0   0   0   0.965638766519824   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0220264317180617  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.963656387665198   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0220264317180617  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.961674008810573   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0220264317180617  0   0   0   0.966960352422908   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0264317180616740  0   0   0   0.961233480176212   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0264317180616740  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.959251101321586   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0264317180616740  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.957268722466960   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0264317180616740  0   0   0   0.962555066079295   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0308370044052863  0   0   0   0.956828193832599   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0308370044052863  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.954845814977974   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0308370044052863  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.952863436123348   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0308370044052863  0   0   0   0.958149779735683   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0352422907488987  0   0   0   0.952422907488987   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0352422907488987  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.950440528634361   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0352422907488987  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.948458149779736   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0352422907488987  0   0   0   0.953744493392071   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0396475770925110  0   0   0   0.948017621145375   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0396475770925110  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.946035242290749   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0396475770925110  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.944052863436123   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0396475770925110  0   0   0   0.949339207048458   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0440528634361234  0   0   0   0.943612334801762   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0440528634361234  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.941629955947137   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0440528634361234  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.939647577092511   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0440528634361234  0   0   0   0.944933920704846   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0484581497797357  0   0   0   0.939207048458150   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0484581497797357  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.937224669603524   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0484581497797357  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.935242290748899   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0484581497797357  0   0   0   0.940528634361234   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0528634361233480  0   0   0   0.934801762114538   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0528634361233480  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.932819383259912   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0528634361233480  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.930837004405286   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0528634361233480  0   0   0   0.936123348017621   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0572687224669604  0   0   0   0.930396475770925   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0572687224669604  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.928414096916300   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0572687224669604  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.926431718061674   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0572687224669604  0   0   0   0.931718061674009   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0616740088105727  0   0   0   0.925991189427313   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0616740088105727  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.924008810572687   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0616740088105727  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.922026431718062   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0616740088105727  0   0   0   0.927312775330397   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0660792951541850  0   0   0   0.921585903083701   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0660792951541850  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.919603524229075   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0660792951541850  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.917621145374449   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0660792951541850  0   0   0   0.922907488986784   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0704845814977974  0   0   0   0.917180616740088   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0704845814977974  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.915198237885463   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0704845814977974  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.913215859030837   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0704845814977974  0   0   0   0.918502202643172   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0748898678414097  0   0   0   0.912775330396476   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0748898678414097  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.910792951541850   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0748898678414097  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.908810572687225   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0748898678414097  0   0   0   0.914096916299560   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0792951541850220  0   0   0   0.908370044052864   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0792951541850220  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.906387665198238   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0792951541850220  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.904405286343612   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0792951541850220  0   0   0   0.909691629955947   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0837004405286344  0   0   0   0.903964757709251   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850    0.0110132158590308  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0837004405286344  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.901982378854626   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370 0   0.0110132158590308  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0837004405286344  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.900000000000000   0.00198237885462555 0   0   0.0110132158590308  0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0837004405286344  0   0   0   0.905286343612335   0   0   0   0.0110132158590308
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0881057268722467  0   0   0   0.910572687224670   0.000220264317180617    0.000440528634361233    0.000660792951541850
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0881057268722467  0   0   0.000881057268722467    0.908590308370044   0.00110132158590308 0.00132158590308370
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0881057268722467  0   0.00154185022026432 0.00176211453744493 0.906607929515419   0.00198237885462555
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0881057268722467  0   0   0   0.911894273127753];
```

**Question 1:**

Each of the 3 methods yields different result and I am not sure which one to use.
For the iterator method, I know it's an approximation that can be used in the case of big TPMs.

Why there is such a difference in the values?

**Question 2:**

Why I am getting negative values in the stationary distribution?
I used a bigger TPM of size 2600x2600 and I am not getting any negative values, but it's difficult to put 2600x2600 matrix here.

Comment: **(1)** Have you first confirmed all entries in the transition probability matrix are positive and in the interval `[0,1]`?  **(2)** Have you confirmed the row sum is equal to 1 for all rows? `sum(TPM,2)`

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Yes I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No Toolbox Required:**
We know the steady state probabilities are the unique solution to equations below for a Discrete Time Markov Chain (DTMC).

[image: Equations to find steady state distribution (probabilities) for a discrete time Markov chain]

You can rewrite this to show that this distribution must lie in the nullspace of the transition probability matrix (see below). This permits using MATLAB's [`null()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html).

[image: Rewriting the steady state equations to show the steady state distribution lies in the null space of the transition probability matrix]

Normalizing the sum gives the unique solution and satisfies the other equation.

```
P = [.2 .3 .3 0 .2;
    .1 .2 .3 .4 0;
    0 .5 .4 .1 0;
    .2 .2 .2 .3 .1;
    .5 .2 .1 .1 .1];
ssp0 = null(eye(size(P))-P.');
SteadyStateProb = ssp0./sum(ssp0)          % [0.1263 0.3017 0.2969 0.2224 0.0528]
```

Notice the interim `ssp0` has negative values yet the final answer, `SteadyStateProb`, is correct in that all values are valid probabilities and all probabilities sum to 1.

---

**Update based on [OP's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59950322/4): Conditioning the Matrix**

One of the problems with your transition probability matrix, the 84×84 sized `TPM` in your edit, is that the row sum is greater than one.  You can verify this with `find(sum(TPM,2) > 1)` to get the row indices where this occurs. Further, this "overage" is very small: `max(sum(TPM,2))-1` shows the largest row sum exceeds 1 by `4.4409e-16` with for me is twice the `eps` (`2.2204e-16`).

Using the very low-tech code below, I normalized each row.

```
% Re-Normalize:  Divide the kth row by the sum of that row
TPM2 = TPM;
for k = 1:size(TPM2,1)
    TPM2(k,:) = TPM2(k,:)/sum(TPM2(k,:));   
end
```

This results in no row sum exceeding one; you can verify with `find(sum(TPM2,2) > 1)` which returns a 0×1 empty double column vector.

Without further massaging the matrix we can obtain the distribution in steady state.

```
ssp0 = null(eye(size(TPM2))-TPM2.');
SteadyStateProb_TPM2 = ssp0./sum(ssp0);
```

Notice the `min(SteadyStateProb_TPM2)` is `-9.6502e-16` (zero!) and the sum is essentially 1 (`abs(1-sum(SteadyStateProb_TPM2))`).

I would now just force non-negativity.

```
SteadyStateProb_TPM2(SteadyStateProb_TPM2<0) = 0;
```

**Compare to an iterative approximation:**
We know that `TPM2^n` converges to `SteadyStateProb_TPM2` as `n` gets large enough. So let's check it.

We multiply the transition matrix by itself many times (here we get the 2500 step transition matrix). We can see it seems to be converging more or less on target.

```
Approx = TPM2^500;
Approx = Approx*Approx*Approx*Approx*Approx; 

ind = find(SteadyStateProb_TPM2 > 0.05); % find states with steady state prob > 0.05

SteadyStateProb_TPM2(ind).'
Approx(1:6,ind)
```

Note the states are `[4 8 12 16 20 24]`.

> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.0821    0.2052    0.2565    0.2138    0.1336    0.0668
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.0727    0.1818    0.2273    0.1894    0.1184    0.0592
> 0.0760    0.1900    0.2374    0.1979    0.1237    0.0618
> 0.0763    0.1908    0.2385    0.1988    0.1242    0.0621
> 0.0821    0.2052    0.2565    0.2138    0.1336    0.0668
> 0.0727    0.1818    0.2273    0.1894    0.1184    0.0592
> 0.0760    0.1900    0.2374    0.1979    0.1237    0.0618
> ```

Depending on your application, you may consider this iteration method good enough, but I wouldn't use it when the direct analytic methods are still viable. I imagine a 2600×2600 matrix is doable in MATLAB if you take time to ensure it is well-conditioned.

**Update re: [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59950322/stationary-distribution-using-eigenvectors-on-matlab/59950966?noredirect=1#comment106059062_59950966): What about the eigenvalue method?**

It works fine.

```
% Using the 5x5 P matrix from above
[V,D] = eigs(double(P.'),1);
Py = -abs(V)/sum(V)
```

Or alternatively,

```
Pyalt = V./sum(V)
```

You can verify this works on the 84x84 as well:

```
[V2,D2] = eigs(double(TPM2'),1);
Py_TPM2 = -abs(V2)/sum(V2);
Py_TPM2alt = V2./sum(V2); 

% Evaluate to compare
SteadyStateProb_TPM2(ind).'         
Py_TPM2(ind).'
Py_TPM2alt(ind).'
```

which gives the following.  Note the states are `[4 8 12 16 20 24]`.

> `SteadyStateProb_TPM2(ind).' = 0.0821    0.2052    0.2565    0.2138    0.1336    0.0668`
>   `Py_TPM2(ind).'              = 0.0821    0.2052    0.2565    0.2138    0.1336    0.0668`
>   `Py_TPM2alt(ind).'           = 0.0821    0.2052    0.2565    0.2138    0.1336    0.0668`

Comment: I am not sure that I did understand "ssp0 has negative values yet the final answer is correct" you mean that the stat. dist. can contain negative values? Also, I wanted to compare the results of your code and mine and using a TPM that I am sure is a correct one (i.e, verifies the conditions you asked about) and there is a difference in the results. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Does that make it more clear?  Also, can you [edit] your question to include your TPM? (if your TPM is very large, consider constructing a smaller example that represents the issue)

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question, I encluded a link to the TPM I am talking about it's on drive hope it will be useful.

Comment: For security purposes, it would be better if you edited your question to include the TPM in a single code block (which can right scroll). Then we can copy-paste.  Otherwise, are you seeing a discrepancy between your code and this approach?  What about the example I posted?

Comment: @Afo I've updated my answer. Does this answer your question?

Comment: thank you, I will try again using your suggestions with both matrices and I'll keep you updated. I have a question: did you try with the eigenvalues and vectors method? I just wanted to ask because I was trying to compare the 2 stationary distributions yielded especially that I noticed that sum(V1) = sum(V3). Also, is it ok to force non-negativity? maybe it's a silly question but I want my results to be exact

Comment: @Afo I've updated the answer. Eigenvalue approach works fine. You'll get -0.0000000 entries but you can easily clear those as already shown.