# How to visualize Markov Chain transition probabilities in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, markov-chains

I want to visualize my Markov chain using a digraph. I am using the following lines of code:

```
mc = dtmc(TPM,'StateNames',namesStates);
graphplot(mc,'ColorNodes',true,'ColorEdges',true);
```

where `namesStates` is a cell array that contains the names (string) of each node of my MC.

Since the probabilities are so close to each other, I want to visualize the probabilities of each edge of the digraph or the transition rates. Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

Here is a TPM that I am using:

```
0,941033925686591   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000146864444118079    0,0220296666177119  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0,000220296666177119    0,926053752386547   0,000293728888236158    0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0,000367161110295198    0,000440593332354237    0,903730356880599   0   0   0,0587457776472316  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7,34322220590395e-05    0   0   0,940960493464532   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000146864444118079    0,0220296666177119  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   7,34322220590395e-05    0   0,000220296666177119    0,925980320164488   0,000293728888236158    0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000367161110295198    0,000440593332354237    0,903656924658540   0   0   0,0587457776472316  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   7,34322220590395e-05    0   0   0,962990160082244   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000146864444118079    0   0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   7,34322220590395e-05    0   0,000220296666177119    0,962696431194008   0,000293728888236158    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000367161110295198    0,000440593332354237    0,962402702305772   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0,00367161110295198 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,937362314583639   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000146864444118079    0,0220296666177119  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0,00367161110295198 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,000220296666177119    0,922382141283595   0,000293728888236158    0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0,00367161110295198 0   0   0   0   0   0   0,000367161110295198    0,000440593332354237    0,900058745777647   0   0   0,0587457776472316  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0,00367161110295198 0   0   0   0   0   3,85519165809957e-05    0   0   0,937323762667058   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000146864444118079    0,0220296666177119  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0,00367161110295198 0   0   0   0   0   5,07906202575023e-05    0   0,000220296666177119    0,922331350663338   0,000293728888236158    0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0,00367161110295198 0   0   0   0   0   5,87457776472316e-05    0,000367161110295198    0,000440593332354237    0,900000000000000   0   0   0,0587457776472316  0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00367161110295198 0   0   0   0   0   3,85519165809957e-05    0   0   0,959353429284770   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000146864444118079    0   0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00367161110295198 0   0   0   0   0   5,07906202575023e-05    0   0,000220296666177119    0,959047461692858   0,000293728888236158    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198  0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00367161110295198 0   0   0   0   0   5,87457776472316e-05    0,000367161110295198    0,000440593332354237    0,958745777647232   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,0367161110295198
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00734322220590395 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,970406814510207   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000146864444118079    0,0220296666177119  0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00734322220590395 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,000220296666177119    0,955426641210163   0,000293728888236158    0   0,0367161110295198  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00734322220590395 0   0   0   0   0   0   0,000367161110295198    0,000440593332354237    0,933103245704215   0   0   0,0587457776472316  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00734322220590395 0   0   0   0   0   4,40593332354237e-05    0   0   0,970362755176972   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000146864444118079    0,0220296666177119  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00734322220590395 0   0   0   0   0   5,50741665442796e-05    0   0,000220296666177119    0,955371567043619   0,000293728888236158    0   0,0367161110295198  0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00734322220590395 0   0   0   0   0   6,16830665295932e-05    0,000367161110295198    0,000440593332354237    0,933041562637686   0   0   0,0587457776472316
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00734322220590395 0   0   0   0   0   4,40593332354237e-05    0   0   0,992392421794684   7,34322220590395e-05    0,000146864444118079
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00734322220590395 0   0   0   0   0   5,50741665442796e-05    0   0,000220296666177119    0,992087678073139   0,000293728888236158
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,00734322220590395 0   0   0   0   0   6,16830665295932e-05    0,000367161110295198    0,000440593332354237    0,991787340284917
```

instead of:

```
mc = dtmc(TPM,'StateNames',namesStates);
```

We can do:

```
mc = dtmc(TPM);
```

[image]

Comment: Is this the `TPM` from https://stackoverflow.com/q/59950322/8239061?  Or is there a [mcve] you could post? Right now, SO volunteers have no `namesStates` or `TPM` to work with.

Comment: Using your `TPM` from the linked post, I was able to use your code to visualize `mc = dtmc(TPM)` just fine with MATLAB R2019a.   Is the plot working for you?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan I've edited my question: don't bother yourself with **namesStates** it's not important it's only a cell array with nodes names (instead of having numbered nodes I prefer to have the name of the state). I've added a TPM

Comment: Using the `TPM` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59950322/8239061) I was already able to use `mc = dtmc(TPM)` and `graphplot(mc,'ColorNodes',true,'ColorEdges',true);` and have it all work out.    See my comments above.  What output are you getting? What is wrong with the output you get?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the output, I am asking if I can add the probability to go from a node to another on my digraph

Comment: In addition to the colormap already applied to the transition probabilities (arcs)?

Comment: Yes. You can see that the arcs are in blue so you cannot tell the difference in probabilities

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and post the image you get from the plot?  Also, are you wanting text annotations?  That could be tricky for all arcs due to the sheer number.

Comment: You can see in the image that all the edges have the same colors (blue). another solution would be to change the scale in the bar at the right of the image: instead of dividing probabilities: {0 0.1 0.2 0.3 ...} it can be for example {0.001 0.002...} again I am just wondering if it's doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/econ/dtmc.graphplot.html) you can find the 'LabelEdges' parameter, when set to true the probability is also displayed.

```
graphplot(mc,'ColorNodes',true,'ColorEdges',true,'LabelEdges',true);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we change the scale of the bar (transition probability) on the right side of the digraph ?

Comment: Can't answer your question.

Comment: @Afo, if you can access the properties of the colorbar, you can probably control it directly.  [Possibly relevant posts for this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=control+colorbar+in+Matlab).